# In Testing how to decide which one is unit test case and e2e test case?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, e2e-testing

We've written some test cases for "Testing component." But how do we  categorize test case is unit or e2e in Angular.

Comment: Too broad. If it fits the definition of 'unit test', it's unit test. If it fits the definition of 'e2e', it's e2e. I'd suggest to post your current test. May be still too broad and belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but at least can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between unit test and e2e test is what's tested?

**e2e** tests your view and depend of your framework/library and the **unit test** tests your business logic.

If I have a reference of your angular component it's certainly an **e2e test**, something like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoaderComponent } from './loader.component';

describe('LoaderComponent', () => {
  let component: LoaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoaderComponent>; //<- ref of the angular component

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoaderComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If you generate your component with angular CLI, a .spec.ts file is always generate with .css, .html and .ts.

---

If you have no reference to angular of any another third part framework. Your test will be a **unit test**. Something like this:

```
describe("Determine min or max ticket per person", () => {

  it('Should return the max if the min is greater', () => {
    const min = 10
    const max = 5
    expect(TicketDataSpecification.determineMinPerPerson(min, max)).toEqual(max)
  })

  it('Should return the min if the max is less', () => {
    const min = 10
    const max = 5
    expect(TicketDataSpecification.determineMaxPerPerson(min, max)).toEqual(min)
  })

  it('Should return the quantity if the min is greater', () => {
    const min = 10
    const quantity = 5
    expect(TicketDataSpecification.determineMinPerPersonWithQuantity(min, quantity)).toEqual(quantity)
  })

  it('Should return the quantity if the max is greater', () => {
    const max = 10
    const quantity = 5
    expect(TicketDataSpecification.determineMaxPerPersonWithQuantity(max, quantity)).toEqual(quantity)
  })

})
```

After that, you have specification test, integration test, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it:
**Unit test**: Test classes 
**Integration test**: Test component (class + template) using ComponentFixture
**E2E**: Mimic user inputs using Protractor and Selenium